# Asp.Net MVC 3 - How do you Add/Map a view to a project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I created a new MVC 3 project. I ran the project and it loaded the home page. I then added a new view called "discussion.cshtml".

I have 1 controller in the Controllers folder: HomeController

**EDIT** I misspelled Discussion before but it's not misspelled in my project. the problem persists.

the new view is setup in this fashion: View -> Home -> Discussion.cshtml

I added this code to the HomeController

```
 public ActionResult Discussion()
         {
             return View();
         }
```

**Problem:** The view did not load when I hit run. I got the 404 error. The index page loads with this url "localhost:5553". But I tried `"localhost:5553/discussion.cshtml"` and it can't find it. How do I map/route to a view. I'm not sure what's going on, I feel like I'm missing something simple.

The Global.ascx page has the usual default code if it helps:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MvcApplication1
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use this and it will work fine :- localhost:5553/Discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not do like localhost:5553/discussion.cshtml" on mvc.

right click over the Discussion action and select Add View.

if you browse `localhost:5553/Home/Discussion`, that will route to the view you added above.

Comment: Turns out everything was right, but I was adding .cshtml. At first it didn't work when I removed it, but I closed visual studio and cleared my cache and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a typo. Try renaming `Discsussion.cshtml` to `Discussion.cshtml`

And try accessing it http://localhost:5553/home/discussion

Comment: The typo was only in the post not the project. That did not work.

Comment: Can you show more details of the project? How about accessing the Index view? Are you able to view that? Using what URL?

Comment: And when you tried 'http://localhost:5553/home/discussion' have you build or debug (pressing f5)?

Answer (score 0):

With an action that just returns View():

```
 public ActionResult Discussion()
 {
      return View();
 }
```

The ASP.NET MVC engine will look for a file with the same name as the action in the folder with the same name as the controller. In your case, the file name is spelt differently. You could also do:

```
 public ActionResult Discussion()
 {
      return View("Discsussion");
 }
```

This will match your current file name, but it seems its a typo so just rename your file.

Comment: The typo was only in the post not the project. That did not work.